# User can send SMS at scheduled time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

I need some guidance for setting up and allowing a user to send a scheduled message to all subscribers of the twilio number. Should I make model that takes in a string for date and time? I really don't know how to do this at all and I'm pretty new to rails. Any suggestions/ideas would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're app is on Heroku you can use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), though it has its limitations. It works best with rake tasks so I would follow this blog (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/12/sms-alerts-for-urgent-emails-with-twilio-and-the-gmail-api.html) to setup the text message functionality then put that into a rake task which you can then schedule to run periodically.

If you need more specific control on when it's sent then I'd use a background task gem like Delayed Jobs or Redis. Those will be harder to setup though so I'd start with the scheduler and go from there